# How to push add to cart event in datalayer on magento widget

Tags: magento2, addtocart, google-tag-manager

I'm using magento2.4.2 and added catalog widget in homepage.Need to add datalayer to addtocart event in MagentoCatalogWidgets.
Note:Add to cart event for listing and detail pages are working perfectly

Comment: you mean you using 'Catalog Product List' widget?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy yes

Answer (score 0):

the first thing to understand with widget is that the template they use can be configured differently from the pagebuilder, on the screenshot below, we can see the template is: `Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml` (full path: `vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`)

[image]

To customise this template, we know we may add a new file in the folder `app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_CatalogWidget/product/widget/content/grid.phtml`

Once we have this template in the right place, then adding datalayer feature will lead to have the same changes as what was done on other templates.

Comment: Im using enterprise,so for all other templates that was added by default ..but not in widget

Comment: my answer is based on an enterprise environment as well